# C++ - How to find the depth of a given node of a n-ary tree

Tags: c++, tree

```
Class Tree {
  Node* root
public:
  // member functions  
};
```

```
Class Node {
  int data;
  int numChildren;
  Tree* childrens // array of trees
};
```

I want to calculate the depth of a given node in the tree. This is my attempt so far:

```
int Tree::getDepth(const int& data) const {
    if (root) {
        if (root->data == data) return 0; // data found
        for (int i = 0; i < root->numChildren; ++i) // recursive
            return 1 + root->childrens[i].getDepth(data);
    }
    return -1; // empty tree or data not found
}
```

But this will cause trouble. In the very beginning I have to check if the root is nullptr, and in the recursive step, if it meets an empty subtree before it meets the desired node, it will return -1 and the calculation will be wrong. Could you give me some hints on solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the subtrees contains data before entering it.